# Cannot execute batch command after Play Framework command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, playframework-2.0

I've done a small batch script to zip my Play Framework (2.2.1) project into a war and after execute some other batch commands.

When I execute my `.bat`, it execute correctly `play war` command (from Play2War plugin), but I have a `move file.war \out` after and it is not executed, command prompt is closed.

No error is displayed.

Any idea ?

war.bat

```
set pathProject=%cd%
set warName=mywar.war
play war
move "%pathProject%\target\%warName%" "%pathProject%\out\package"
```

Comment: well. you're not showing us all of the .bat file. Echo out the move line and make sure your variables are set the way you expect.

Comment: Hmm. when you do the `play war` command, does it use the mywar.war file? It's possible that it could be locked because it's in use. Add a pause to the end of your batch file so you can see any messages that move outputs.

Comment: is the "play" in "play war" a batch file?

Comment: Solution found ! I modified `play war` line by `call play war` and it execute my `move` line after. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Copied from comment below]

Solution found ! I modified `play war` line by `call play war` and it execute my `move` line after. Thanks anyway